# Why Math.sqrt() outputs wrong value in java?

Tags: java, math

```
long mynum = Long.parseLong("7660142319573120");
long ans = (long)Math.sqrt(mynum) // output = 87522239
long ans_ans = ans * ans;
```

In this case, I am getting ans_ans > mynum where it should be <=mynum. Why such behavior? I tried this with node js as well. There also result is same.

Comment: You can write `long mynum = 7660142319573120L;` instead of using parseLong. Not related to question, just general remark.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `Math.sqrt` with a long.
As the JavaDoc points out, it returns a "correctly rounded value".

Since your square-root is not an non-comma-value (`87522238,999999994`), your result is rounded up to your output `87522239`.

After that, the square of the value is intuitively larger than `mynum`, since you multiply larger numbers than the root!

Comment: If it is rounding then answer of Math.sqrt(15) should be 4 as it is 3.872983346207417

Comment: @AbhilashMandaliya yes, that's right, the result of Math.sqrt() is double, but in your example it's casted to long: (long)Math.sqrt(mynum) so it's automatically rounded. try Math.sqrt(15) and (long)Math.sqrt(15) to see the difference

Comment: It comes 3 only as @IfOnly has mentioned below

Comment: @AbhilashMandaliya normally casting to long gives you a number truncated towards zero, but in your case from the example with mynum, it was too big to be stored in a double, I suppose

Comment: @AbhilashMandaliya: There are *two* places where the sqrt value is being modified. (1) The `Math.sqrt` call rounds the true mathematical result to the nearest representable double. (2) The conversion of that double to `long` *truncates* rather than rounds. In your particular case, it just so happens that the rounding of the `Math.sqrt` result takes you from something just under an integer *up* to exactly that integer. As @Lutz explains in his (IMO excellent) answer, this is quite unusual, and only happens for a handful of exactly representable integers.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.sqrt` operates on `double`s, not `long`s, so `mynum` gets converted to a `double` first. This is a 64-bits floating point number, which has "15–17 decimal digits of precision" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

Your input number has 16 digits, so you may be losing precision on the input already. You may also be losing precision on the output.

If you really need an integer square root of `long` numbers, or generally numbers that are too big for accurate representation as a `double`, look into [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) algorithms.

You can also use [`LongMath.sqrt()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/LongMath.java#L312) from the Guava library.

Answer (score 3):

```
double ans = (double)Math.sqrt(15);
System.out.println("Double : " + ans);
double ans_ans = ans * ans;
System.out.println("Double : " + ans_ans);

long ans1 = (long)Math.sqrt(15);
System.out.println("Long : " + ans1);
long ans_ans1 = ans1 * ans1;
System.out.println("Long : " + ans_ans1);
```

Results :

```
Double : 3.872983346207417
Double : 15.000000000000002
Long : 3
Long : 9
```

I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better. [how-to-answer-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: rounding.
The result of `(Long)Math.sqrt(7660142319573120)` is `87522239`, but the mathematical result is `87522238,999999994287166259537761...`. 
if you multiply the `ans` value, which is rounded up in order to be stored as a whole number, you will get bigger number than multiplying the exact result.

Comment: If it is rounding then answer of Math.sqrt(15) should be 4 as it is 3.872983346207417

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the long type, all numbers are representable in `double`, and `Math.sqrt` first converts to double then computes the square root via FPU instruction (on a standard PC).

This situation occurs for numbers `b=a^2-1` where `a` is an integer in the range

```
67108865 <= a <= 94906265
```

The square root of `b` has a series expansion starting with

```
a-1/(2*a)-1/(8*a^2)+...
```

If the relative error `1/(2*a^2)` falls below the machine epsilon, the closest representable `double` number is `a`.

On the other hand for this trick to work one needs that `a*a-1.0` is exactly representable in `double`, which gives the conditions

```
1/(2*a^2) <mu=2^(-53) < 1/(a^2)
```

or

```
2^52 < a^2 < 2^53
2^26+1=67108865 <= a <= floor(sqrt(2)*2^26)=94906265
```